# Django and knockoutjs (foreach)

Tags: python, django, foreach, knockout.js

In views:

```
 posts = Posts.objects.filter(...)
        template = loader.get_template('...')
        context = Context({
            'comments': comments,
            })
        return HttpResponseForbidden(template.render(RequestContext(request, context)))
```

In template:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    head.js('...');
    head.ready(function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            postModel = new postModel({
                posts: '{{ posts }}'
            });
            ko.applyBindings(commentModel, $('#posts')[0]); 

        });
    });
    </script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: comments">
....
</ul>
```

In post.js

```
self.comments = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.parseJson(config.comments)); //error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & 
self.comments = ko.observableArray(config.comments); //error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in
```

How to convert the data type?

```
{{ posts}}
 [<Post: un posts!>, <Post: deux posts!>] to [{id:1, content:'un posts' etc},{...}]
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you are asking here.

Comment: Try to dump your models to JSON first.

Comment: How i can do it, tell me, please? it is in views?

Comment: I handed format json (serializers.serialize("json", posts.objects.filter(...)). to the success of this has not.

Comment: how to trabslate {
    "pk": 1,
    "model": "store.book",
    "fields": {
        "name": "Mostly Harmless",
        "author": ["Douglas", "Adams"]
    }
} to [{"name":"...",...}]

Answer (score 0):

in scripts:

```
postModel = new postModel({
                posts: '{{ posts.fields }}'
            });
            ko.applyBindings(postModel, $('#post')[0]);
```

it's work) 
merci beaucoup)